# I want to Create a dataframe with two columns, one for the duplicate value and the other with all the column's name with that value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I want to know what columns display the same value in a table so, I can remove the duplicates from that table.

What I've done is:
-Remove all na values.
-Then find the columns with duplicates
But I want to add a column called "value'

The final goal would be a data frame (with different data type) something like that:

|   Field_name      |   Value                   |

| Y,Z,T             |  0                        |
| A,B,C             |  "hello"                  |
| timestamp, time   |  '2020-01-01 00:00:00'    |

That's the code I used:

```
# import pandas library  
import pandas as pd 
  
# This function take a dataframe 
# as a parameter and returning list 
# of column names whose contents  
# are duplicates. 
def getDuplicateColumns(pdf): 
  
    # Create an empty set 
    duplicateColumnNames = set() 
      
    # Iterate through all the columns  
    # of dataframe 
    for x in range(pdf.shape[1]): 
          
        # Take column at xth index. 
        col = pdf.iloc[:, x] 
          
        # Iterate through all the columns in 
        # DataFrame from (x + 1)th index to 
        # last index 
        for y in range(x + 1, pdf.shape[1]): 
              
            # Take column at yth index. 
            otherCol = pdf.iloc[:, y] 
              
            # Check if two columns at x & y 
            # index are equal or not, 
            # if equal then adding  
            # to the set 
            if col.equals(otherCol): 
                duplicateColumnNames.add(pdf.columns.values[y]) 
                  
    # Return list of unique column names  
    # whose contents are duplicates. 
    return list(duplicateColumnNames) 
  
# Driver code 
if __name__ == "__main__" : 
  
 
  
  
    # Get list of duplicate columns 
    duplicateColNames = getDuplicateColumns(pdf) 
  
    print('Duplicate Columns are :') 
        
    # Iterate through duplicate 
    # column names 
    for column in duplicateColNames : 
       print('Column Name : ', column, 'Value : ', )
```

Comment: It's always better to provide sample data

Comment: How can I create a table?